# Best way to create new DOM elements using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

is it better to create a DOM element like this:-

```
            var option='';
            var objY = $('select[name="yaxis"]');
            for(var key in summaryObj)
            {
                option += '<option value="'+summaryObj[key]+'">'+key+'</option>';
            }
            objY.html(option);
```

or like this,

```
            var objY = $('select[name="yaxis"]');
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            for(var key in summaryObj)
            {
                var san = summaryObj[key];
                objY.append($(option).clone().attr({value:san,text:key}));
            }
```

Comment: The first one is more performant for sure. Now, if you don't have so many keys in object, use the one you find the most readable. Imho, the first one still win

Comment: I think the second one would be more performant. if it used `cloneNode` and not jQuery in the loop. It's generally faster to clone than to create strings of HTML

Comment: @adeneo regarding string concatenation vs cloneNode, i didn't know that, thx for the input

Comment: @adeneo yes but updating the DOM element by element doesn't seem like a great idea. Personally I'd build a jQuery object instead of a string and then append it at the end.

Comment: @Pointy - forgot to mention that, it's probably not faster when the DOM is changes on each iteration, using a fragment is key

Comment: As as side note, both methods don't work the same if `objY` not empty

Answer (score 2):

For perfomance, this is probably among the fastest ways

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
var frag   = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var key in summaryObj) {
    var clone = option.cloneNode();
    clone.value = san;
    clone.innerHTML = key;

    frag.appendChild(clone);
}

$('select[name="yaxis"]').append(frag);
```

For readability, I like this

```
var objY = $('select[name="yaxis"]');
var frag = [];

$.each(summaryObj, function(key, val) {
    frag.push(
        $('<option />', {
            value : san,
            text  : key
        })
    );
});

objY.append(frag);
```

Comment: And now a jsPerf would be great ;)  >> if you have enough time in hand, for sure... I'm a lazy boy :(

Comment: @A.Wolff - Give me a second, still testing something ?

Comment: @A.Wolff - Here's a [**Perf**](http://jsperf.com/fragments-jquery-and-more), took some time as I was testing a theory. It actually seems it makes more difference to use `html()` instead of `append()`, then what is being used to iterate. `append()` is just so much slower than `html()`

Comment: Again, thank you for the jsPerf. Just wondering, what was your theory?

Comment: @A.Wolff - I just remembered that jQuery uses `domManip` for `append`, which does a whole lot of internal work checking for table structures, strings, clones and builds fragments etc. from strings, while `html` short circuts for native DOM nodes and strings, and goes straight for `innerHTML`, unless it's a jQuery element, then it runs `this.empty().append( node )`. Anyway, running `html` when it's a native DOM node or string is *a lot* faster than `append`.

Comment: `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` might be even faster than constructing a fragment incrementally since it can use the browser's DOM parser

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you Do it like this:

```
var select = $('<select>').attr('name','yaxis');
var option = $("<option>");
option.text('word').value('word');
select.append(option);
```

Comment: or `var option = $("<option/>", { text: word, value: word});`